# do pure virtual functions prevent implicitly generated move constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-semantics

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct test {
    virtual void foo() noexcept = 0;
};

struct test2 : test {
    void foo() noexcept override final {}   
};

// fails
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<test>::value, "test not move constructible");
// succeeds
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<test2>::value, "test2 not move constructible");
```

[(Live)](http://ideone.com/PlJlo4)
According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) (and as far as I understand), `test` should have an implicitly-generated move constructor:

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move constructor for class T is defined as *deleted* in any of the following is true:
>
> - T [= test] has non-static data members that cannot be moved (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors)
> - T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be moved (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors)
> - T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor
> - T is a union and has a variant member with non-trivial copy constructor
> - (until C++14) T has a non-static data member or a direct or virtual base without a move constructor that is not trivially copyable.

Why does the compiler not generate an implicit move constructor for `test`? Any why does it do so for `test2`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`std::is_move_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) checks whether the type can be constructed from an rvalue argument. `test` is an abstract class type. It cannot be constructed at all, regardless of argument.

Comment: Does this mean that `test` does/might have an implicit move constructor, although it is useless for the class itself?

Comment: @MartinD. Yes. In fact, we know it does, since `is_move_constructible<test2>` is true.